# What does "You must long for the next life" means?

Tags: word-meaning, idioms

This is a phrase from the new episode of TV show Game of Thrones. Some context: Jaime Lannister (a knight) is speaking with High Sparrow (a priest) during funeral ceremony. They don't like each other.

> High Sparrow said:
>   *Do you know why we use these stones? To remind us not to fear death. We close our eyes on this world and open them on the next.*
>
> Jaime answered:
>   *You must long for the next life.*

I don't understand, what does it means. Is it an idiom (the whole phrase) or just special meaning of "must long"? Does it mean threat or insult or anything else?

Comment: Did you look up what "long" means as a verb?

Comment: it's in any English>Russian dictionary:to long for, to yearn for=to very much want something, in your soul.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I began learn English when I was 7 years old, now I am 35 (sorry, I wasn't a good learner all this years). I've never met the word `long` used as a verb, and even couldn't imagine that it could be a verb. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: Hi Dimitry, and welcome to ELL. I think the language in Game of Thrones is particularly difficult to understand - sometimes even for native speakers. We can help you with the connotations, but please look up the word that's confusing you in a dictionary to see if you can get any ideas and let us know what you find. If the dictionary is unclear, we can help with that also. We just ask that you do a little research first. I think you did a great job in your question of providing all the context that we might need to understand the sentence, and I hope we will see more of your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In colloquial terms, Jaime is saying:

> You must really, really want to die (and experience whatever comes after).

To long is defined as:

> to have a strong wish or desire.

according to the Oxford Web Dictionary.

It has a similar meaning to want, but is much stronger.  As Lambie mentioned, it is almost an exact synonym of "yearn."

You should note that Jaime is being sarcastic when he says this.  He's making fun of High Sparrow's attitudes towards death.